# How to generate fixed webhook url?

Tags: python, twilio, webhooks

I am using Twilio to send and receive SMS messages from a Python application. The issue is that their tutorials use ngrok as a way to get through the firewall but I don't want to have to run ngrok every time I run my app and the URL changes every time ngrok runs so I have to change the webhook url on Twilio every time. Is there a better way around this? Is this something that requires a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options that you have.

1. The paid option of ngrok allows you to set a persistent url so that you don't have to chance the webhook url on Twilio each time.
2. If you have a server, then you would also be able to set a persistent url to your server.

Unfortunately, the free version of ngrok does not allow you to set a persistent url.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at going Serverless with Twilio Functions (Node.js/JavaScript).

Building Apps with Twilio Functions
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007737928-Building-apps-with-Twilio-Functions